# How can Xcode 8 be aware of my shell environment variables?

Tags: ruby, xcode, bash, shell, xcode8

In Xcode 8.x, at compilation time, I want to run a Ruby script using the environment variables of my shell environment. Unfortunately, when I add a *Run Script Phase* to my target's build phases, my Ruby script can't find the environment variables from my shell environment.

For instance, I'd like this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require('plist')

open('myProperties.plist', 'w') do |f|
  f << {
    :'myProperty' => ENV['MY_PROPERTY'].to_s
  }.to_plist
end
```

to generate a `.plist` file with data from my environment.

Ultimately, my purpose is to provide a convenient way to use secret API keys in an open-source iOS project needing such keys to work properly. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: why don't you just loop through the env variables you want to add? A Ruby instance should be aware of any env's present in the current shell execution environment when started. If the variables aren't found when you try to add them in ruby it's because they don't exist in that ruby execution context. You need to figure out why they don't exist in the shell environment where ruby is executed.

Comment: @Thermatix "Why they don't exist in the shell environment where ruby is executed" = that's exactly my question. That's Xcode shell environment. How can I make it "inherit" my shell environment variables?

Comment: Well, after some looking, for gui apps you have to set envs like this: http://codepulsive.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x.html

Comment: @Thermatix: this blog post is just about env variables in OS X, not at all about Xcode. It's not relevent for my question.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this? I'm trying this for the exact same purpose.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves I didn't :(

Comment: I did. I’m writing a post on medium about it.

Comment: Well not really. But a workaround.

Comment: Don't forget to post the link once you've published it.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves can you explain how did you manage to do that please ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@nunogonalves/handling-secrets-in-ios-open-source-projects-b5a212f4e28c

Comment: @DirtyHenry let me know if it helps.

Comment: Good idea to source an env file from Xcode!  Thanks!